# How to add scroll into TabLayoutPanel (GWT) tab bar

Tags: gwt

Any idea how to add "slider" to the `TabLayoutPanel` (GWT) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a proper answer to forward something but [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/wN8lLU23wPA) can help you.
I also tried with the code to see the scroll button not able to see it.
May in this case you need to do a custom implementation for this.

Comment: I saw this solution yesterday as well.. it's a bit incomplete, but it's a good entry point.. anyway I haven't found better example..